# Inherited global variable cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am writing a small program that is supposed to create differently shaped rooms from a base of a square. The shapes are supposed to inherit from the square, which contains List of their vertices.

`Room` (Parent class) code:

```
class Room
{
    private List<Point> vertices;
    private int oX;
    private int oY;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Room(int oX, int oY, int width, int height)
    {
        vertices = new List<Point>();
        addVertice(new Point(oX, oY));
        addVertice(new Point(oX + width, oY));
        addVertice(new Point(oX, oY + height));
        addVertice(new Point(oX + width, oY + height));

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
   }
}
```

Then I inherit `LShape` from `Room`, but the Visual Studio says that the **`vertices`** variable cannot be accessed due to its protection level.

Code for `LShape` (child) class

```
class LShape: Room
{
    public LShape(int oX, int oY, int width, int height, List<Point> verticesList)
    {
        vertices = verticesList;
    }
}
```

According to all the tutorials I found, this should be working, even if the parent's members are private.

Can someone explain to me where my error is, or where am I misunderstanding the concepts? Also If you have any good tutorials on inheritance, I'd be thankful.

Thank you.

Comment: This is because `vertices` is marked as `private` in the base `Room` class.  You could nest the derived class inside of `Room` and have it accessible though I'm not sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 9):

> According to all the tutorials I found, this should be working, even if the Parent's members are private.

No, private members are only accessible within the program text of the declaring type. So if you declare `LShape` as a *nested* type within `Room`, that will work - but otherwise it won't. You'd have access to it if it were a `protected` member instead, but I'd suggest keeping it `private` anyway, to be honest - instead, pass the vertices up to the constructor.

Note that your `LShape` constructor will need to chain to an accessible constructor in `Room`, too (or another `LShape` constructor, but eventually it'll have to chain up to `Room`).

Comment: I understand the first bit, but the note at the end. can you clarify that, as to why and how do i Chain it up?

Comment: @Yakuman: You chain to another constructor with `: this(...)` or `: base(...)`. It's not really what your main question is about though, so I suggest you read up more on constructors in derived classes in whatever books/tutorials you're using. See also http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html

Answer (score 5):

That's because you declared `vertices` as `private`:

```
private List<Point> vertices;
```

`private` means that **only the declaring** type (or types nested in this type) can access this field. If you want to make this field accessible from inheriting classes, you need to declare it as `protected`:

```
protected List<Point> vertices;
```

For more information see [C# access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).